# How can I clear blocked IP's from windows firewall?

Tags: windows, firewall

I have a block rule in windows firewall and under the Scope tab it has hundreds of individual addresses that were added at some point.  I am finding I have to click IP and remove for each address.

Is there a way of either scripting or somehow clear the whole list?

Comment: Windows PoweShell should have functions to manage firewall rules.

Comment: I know of some that allow add/remove rules, but not any that allow remove multiple ip's

Answer (score 1):

Try this (you can use Powershell ISE):

```
$ruleName = "NAME" # change name
$addrToDelete= "1.2.3.4" # change address

$rules=Get-NetFirewallRule -Enabled True |?{$_.DisplayName -eq $ruleName}
$allAddr=$rules[0] | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LocalAddress # LocalAddres or RemoteAddress
$inputObj=$rules[0] | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter
$delAddr=$allAddr -eq $addrToDelete
$allAddr = $allAddr -replace $delAddr -replace ""
$allAddrAfter = $AllAddr -join ''
Set-NetFirewallAddressFilter -InputObject $inputObj -LocalAddress $allAddrAfter
```

To delete multiple addresses:

```
$ipsToRemove = @("1.2.3.4", "4.3.2.1") # paste addresses that you want to remove
$ruleName = "test" # name of the firewall role
$rules = Get-NetFirewallRule -Enabled True | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq $ruleName }
$inputObj = $rules[0] | Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter 
$allAddr = $inputObj | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LocalAddress # LocalAddresses or RemoteAddresses
$filteredAddresses = $allAddr | Where-Object{ $_ -notin $ipsToRemove }
Set-NetFirewallAddressFilter -InputObject $inputObj -LocalAddress $filteredAddresses # LocalAddresses or RemoteAddresses
```

This script removes LocallAdresses - if you want to remove RemoteAddresses you need to change it in 5 and last line of the code.

Comment: Will check this out.  What if you have hundreds of addresses?

Comment: Check my answer again. I created second script do delete more addresses.